# How to get the SUMPRODUCT of unequal arrays Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, formula

[Google states that](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294) SUMPRODUCT "calculates the sum of the products of corresponding entries in two equal-sized arrays or ranges".

What I want to do is get the sum of the products of corresponding entries in two **unequal**-sized arrays.  Such a thing can be accomplished with Excel:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(A1:Z1,2)>5)*(A2:Z10="self"))
```

This will display a sum of all the times when "self" occurs in rows 2 through 10 where row 1 is a weekend.  In Google Spreadsheets, the equivalent should be

```
=ArrayFormula( SUMPRODUCT(WEEKDAY(A1:Z1,2)> 5, A2:Z10="self" ) )
```

However because Google Spreadsheets can only accept equal-sized arrays, this will fail.  So as I see it I have three options:

1. Insert 8 more rows between row 1 and 2 with a copy of all the dates from
   row 1
2. Redo the formula with 8 sums, ex.:

> =ArrayFormula( SUMPRODUCT(...)) + ArrayFormula( SUMPRODUCT(...)) ...etc...

3. Find another formula that will work more efficiently

So the question boils down to point 3 - what other formulas could I use to make an array sum of rows 2 through 10 so that I can multiply them inside of SUMPRODUCT?  Or is there another function that would help me accomplish the same thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how I missed it, but the code for Excel works perfectly in Google Spreadsheets as well.  So here's the final answer:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT( ( weekday(A1:Z1,2)>5 ) * ( A2:Z10 = "self" ) ))
```

Hopefully someone else finds this useful!

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to post your own answer, yes I found this useful, cheers!